# Contextual view that limits results?

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms

This is a hard one to explain, so thanks for taking a look.  I've created a menu in views of all the nodes associated with a particular taxonomy term.  The problem is that some of these nodes have children associated with them that I do not want to show in the views menu.  BUT, they should still display the menu.

> Node 1 
>   Node 2 
>   - (child) Node 2a 
>   - (child) Node 2b 
>   Node 3

In that example, the menu would show up on all 5 pages, but would only have 3 items in the menu.

I am able to make a menu of all the items associated with a term, but can't figure out how to add depth.  Any ideas?
-JB

Answer (score 0):

A better understanding of contextual filters led me to a solution.  I used a contextual filter to limit which pages showed the menu, then used a filter to control the items.